# MapKit lesson in SwiftUI giving compiler errors

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-map

I'm following the "Creating and Combining View" lesson on SwiftUI. However when I tried to use the MapKit, my simulator doesn't work as it is supposed to work (which is show the pin at the assigned Coordinates)

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit


struct MapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Map(initialPosition: .region(region))
    }


    private var region: MKCoordinateRegion {
        MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
        )
    }
}


#Preview {
    MapView()
}
```

What I expected to happen:
[image]

What actually happened
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using iOS 17?

Comment: see the official docs of how a `Map` can be used here [Map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map). Which code are you using, the code in your question or the code in your picture? Note to show the map, you need to put `MapView()` into your `ContentView`, replacing the "hello world" code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The code that I've provided and the code in the picture are identical. The problem is based on the Swift official tutorial, it should show a map in the simulator, however, mine shows and error like the two last pictures.

Comment: your question code shows this: `#Preview { MapView() }` your picture does not. What system are you using and targeting? Show the code for your `ContentView` the view with "hello world", it may help.

Comment: So apparently the Apple tutorial is based on Xcode 15 (which isn't mentioned in the tutorial). If you have Xcode 14, you need to change the `Map(...` line to the one in the answer from @user3613987.

Answer (score 5):

Please use the Map and init function as below.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(region), interactionModes: [])
    }
    
    private var region: MKCoordinateRegion {
        MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
        )
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your Xcode to version 15.0.1.
If you don't see available Xcode updates, you need to update your MacOS first to Sonoma 14.0.

Maybe there are other solutions, but this one worked for me.